# Is it possible to automate NFC payment tests for Android?

Tags: java, android, automation, appium, ui-automation

I'm testing an app that supports NFC payments, however I was unable to find any solutions on automating these tests.
I'm using Appium as my open-source automation tool.

Fully automate NFC payments with desired variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not supported by appium neither any other framework. However, I have a solution for you. Have your app's developers add a menu for you with several choices, each choice represents a payment scenario from your design. Once you click on each one of them, it will mock the real NFC action. Make sure that this menu is only in debug mode and not in release mode.